# Distinguish the "Our system has identified this post as possible spam..." notice from the post it applies to

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, review

On [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), many of our questions ask about statements similar to the "Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully" notice that appears when a post seems suspicious, so when I first encountered it, I initially read it as part of the post and not as a warning.

It would be nice if the notice was more obviously not part of the post, either by adding a background color, separating it from the post with a line, changing the font, or something similar. The indentation is just not enough given the wide line spacing text has these days.

> [image: screenshot showing that indentation is the only thing that visually distinguishes the notice from the post being reviewed.]

Comment: [Yes, this is a good idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366642/295232).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has been fixed. The notice is now styled as a "warning" and should stand out more:

[image]

This screenshot is from the Suggested Edits queue, but the same styling applies to all the others.